# BottomSheet using childFragmentManager but it opens in other fragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog, android-navigation, android-deep-link

I use navigation and

I show BottomSheet in Home_Fragment like this:

```
myBottomSheet!!.show(childFragmentManager, MyBottomSheet.TAG)
```

I thought chainging `requireActivity().supportFragmentManager` to `childFragmentManager` can solve this problem.

But when I open B_Fragment by deeplink, it opens Splash->Login Check->Home_Fragment->B_Fragment

What I expected was dismissing the dialog automatically when Home_Fragment is destroyed. But B_Fragment is still alive(Even though I call dismiss() right before navigate() method.)

I am using Navigation and I tried with `<dialog>` tag & `app:launchSingleTop="true"`. But it didn't work.